Share Realm Data between iOS and WatchOS
In Swift UIKit -
i want to set the same filePath of the realm Database saving file to save the data from watchOS app and the mobile app.i have tried but the same filePath for the realmDatabase not set.
i am using this code for set the same filePath of the realm.
i have also add the appGroups for my both target (Main Mobile App and WatchOS App).
here is the code -
let container = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "AppGroupID")
let realmURL = container.appendingPathComponent("default.realm")
        let config = Realm.Configuration(
            fileURL: realmURL,
            schemaVersion: 1,
            migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
                if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
                    
                }
            }
        )
        
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
        print(config)
        


Welcome to SO. Not sure the question is clear but if you have two different devices you would need to use sync'ing to share data between them. Perhaps if you clarified the question a bit we would be more help. Also, please ensure posted code is properly formatted for readability - use the code formatting tools {}.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
